# How to create an img and set its position to cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do some web-page constructor and faced a problem – I have area to where you can drop image from your pc and it will be placed on the page.

However when img is created it places to the top 0 and left 0 (as it should be, of course). The question is:

How should I modify my code to create an img and set its **left** and **top** to be the same as the cursor position at the moment when you drop img to area.

Here's my code:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var img = $('<img class="draggable">')
            img.attr('src', reader.result);
            img.appendTo(document.body);
            var $draggable = $('.draggable').draggabilly({
                containment: '#none'
            })
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** `.draggable` class already have `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mousemove event to track mouse position within your "stage" div and place the image as in the code below:

```js
var divPos = {};
var offset = $("#stage").offset();
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    divPos = {
        left: e.pageX - offset.left,
        top: e.pageY - offset.top
    };
});

$("#stage").click(function(){
   var i_width = 20
   var i_height = 20
   
   var img = $("<img width="+i_width+" height="+i_height+" src='https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/96746-200.png'/>")
   
   img.css("position","absolute");
   img.css("left",(divPos.left-(i_width/2))+"px");
   img.css("top",(divPos.top-(i_height/2))+"px");
   $("#stage").append(img)
})
```

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 20px;
  
}

#stage {
  background: gray;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Click inside gray area to place image</h1>
<div id="stage"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your .draggable also have body as a parent, then

Simply set offset to img from what your  $draggable was:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
            var img = $('<img class="draggable">')
            img.attr('src', reader.result);
            img.appendTo(document.body);
            var $draggable = $('.draggable');
            img.offset($draggable.offset);
            $draggable.draggabilly({
                containment: '#none'
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to get the cursor coordinates, and assuming you have some function handling the drop-event, you could use the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the event:

```
function drop(event){
    var xcoord = event.clientX;
    var ycoord = event.clientY;
}
```

And these coordinates you could subsequently use in your `reader.onload` function, for example by making them global variables or passing them as argument to the `readURL` funtion, really depending on how you have structured the rest of your code.